# How to group files together in upload

Tags: php, file-upload

What is the most efficient way to group a bunch of file uploads together on the following screen?  I currently have http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ implemented on one of my websites, and I use a hidden field with some random generated id that gets passed into the next page.  This has proven to be unreliable, and I was wondering if someone had a better way of making sure all of the XHR files responses are grouped together on the next page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you mean by grouping the files, but if you want to make sure the files are legit, perhaps using a SESSION key will help.

Comment: I've had some issues in the past where the SESSION information doesn't hold true until the next page and gets lost.  But if no one proposes a better solution I will probably go with this again.  My question is then what happens if a person opens up a second upload page?  Is the SESSION key lost since a new one is assigned?

Comment: @MasterGberry: Ensure the sessions are set prior to loading the page. Make sure all your php scripts use session_start() prior to using them. You shouldn't have any issues. 

For separate pages, perhaps you can have a unique session key for that page -- then in your upload handler, reference the key.